# Finding extremes for function $f(t,x,y,z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, optimization

Find the extremal values of $f(t,x,y,z)=t^2+3x^2+0.3y^2+12z^2$ on the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^4$. Justify your answer.

First of all I think it should be translated into finding extreme values of $f$ subject to the unit sphere constraint which is $g(t,x,y,z)=t^2+x^2+y^2+z^2$.

So I took derivations $\frac{df}{dt}=2t$, $\frac{df}{dx}=6x$, $\frac{df}{dy}=0.6y$, $\frac{df}{dz}=24z$. Obviously the critical point is $(t,x,y,z)=(0,0,0,0)$.

Then I took derivatives of the constraint: $\frac{dg}{dt}=2t$, $\frac{dg}{dx}=2x$, $\frac{dg}{dy}=2y$, $\frac{dg}{dz}=2z$.

Now we have: $2t=\lambda*2t$, $6x=\lambda*2x$, $0.6y=\lambda*2y$, $24z=\lambda*2z$. Also, $g(t,x,y,z)=t^2+x^2+y^2+z^2$ should be taken into account.

That's where I got stuck!

Comment: Perhaps you’re stuck because you’ve only defined the function $g$, but you haven’t expressed a constraint yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $t\ne0$, the equation $2t=2\lambda t$ gives $\lambda=1$. Substituting into the other equations gives $x=y=z=0$, and the constraint $g(t,0,0,0)=t^2=1$ yields $t=\pm1$. The value of $f$ at these points is $1$. I'll leave finding the other potential extrema to you.

---

It's no coincidence that the values of the Lagrange multiplier that you end up with are the half-lengths of the axes of the ellipsoid $f(t,x,y,z)=1$. Here’s an alternative approach that doesn’t involve Langrange multipliers.

The function $f$ is a quadratic form, so its maximum value on the unit sphere is given by the greatest eigenvalue of the associated matrix. Similarly, its minimum value will correspond to the least eigenvalue. In this case, there are no mixed terms—the level-surface ellipsoids are aligned with the coordinate axes—so the eigenvalues are simply the coefficients, and the associated eigenspaces are the respective coordinate axes. So, $f$ will have a maximum value of $12$ along the $z$-axis and a minimum of $0.3$ along the $y$-axis.